# what differences between two bellow scatter files for CPP compiler and linker?

Tags: c++, linker, arm, compiler-construction, sim800

In the project this scatter file:

```
APP  0x90309000 0x000B0000
{
  APPCFG +0
  { 
      * (APP_CFG)
  }

  APP0 +0
  { 
    main.o* (APPENTRY)
  }
  APP1 +0
  {
    main.o* (+RO)
    *.o*    (+RO)
  }

  APP_RAM   0xF0380000 0x00060000
  {
    main.o  (+RW,+ZI)
    *.o     (+RW,+ZI)
  }  
}
```

modify to:

```
APP  0x90309000 0x00030000
{
  APPCFG +0
  { 
      * (APP_CFG)
  }

  APP0 +0
  { 
    main.o* (APPENTRY)
  }
  APP1 +0
  {
    main.o* (+RO)
    *.o*    (+RO)
  }

  APP_RAM   0xF0380000 0x00060000
  {
    main.o  (+RW,+ZI)
    *.o     (+RW,+ZI)
  }  
}
```

In the project it changed and change allowable maximum size of  proggram and linker given bellow error:

> armlink : error L6220:  Load region APP size (197016 bytes) exceeds limit (196608 bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *only* difference is that the size of the `APP` region in memory (the second `APP` parameter) was lowered from `0x000B0000` (decimal `720896`) to `0x00030000` (decimal `196608`).

The two `APP` parameters are:

- `0x90309000`: The start address of the `APP` region in memory.
- `0x00030000`: The size of the `APP` region in memory.

The new size constraint is the reason why you see

> `armlink : error L6220: Load region APP size (197016 bytes) exceeds limit (196608 bytes).`

You may be able to raise the size limit to `0x00030198` (or perhaps even `0x00030200`) to make it accept the `197016` bytes required - but after looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76499444/7582247), I assume that's not an option because the `EEP` region starts at `0x30000` bytes after the `APP` region:

```cpp
/*********************SIM808 EAT Flash Map****************************/
//  APP1 = 192K @ 0X90309000
//  EEP = 8K    @ 0X90339000
```

So:

- You need to make your compiled program smaller by at least 408 bytes.

Comment: What does mean the APP parameter?

Comment: The APP parameter is on the first parameter in your scatter file. It was previously `0x000B0000`  and is now `0x00030000`. Which scatter file documentation are you reading? If you give me a link to it, I can add references to the answer.

Comment: I don't have a proper document for it. Can you suggest a document for it?

Comment: @Hossein No, unfortunately. I pieced it together by clicking around at [ARM Compiler armlink User Guide Version 5.06](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0474/m/scatter-file-syntax). Perhaps that's the correct one. Anyway, did my answer answer what the difference is between the two scatter files you asked about?

Comment: yeah, your answer was right, I reduce the volume of the program and it became ok.
Thanks Ted.

Comment: Now I have a new quick question.

Comment: @Hossein Great! You're welcome! Ok, post a new question and if I know the answer, I will try to answer it.

Comment: What  APP_RAM  is it used for?

Comment: @Hossein I'm guessing that it's following the same pattern as for `APP`. `0xF0380000` means the start address of the random access memory and `0x00060000` is the size (393216 bytes). I could however find even less information about that region online so it's a best guess.